# IRow all cell merage

Tags: c#, npoi

I am using NPOI and I want to merge all cells in a single row.

example:

```
NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress crart = new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(rowindex, rowindex, 2, columnCount >= 2 ? columnCount : 2 + columnCount);
sheet.AddMergedRegion(crart);
```

Comment: So... what's the question? Does that code not work? What happens?

Comment: i am using npoi lib to use my code to generate excel file.

Comment: after cell merge bug not allowed more thane 32767 character in cell